# Don't understand SIFT algorithm

Tags: sift

SIFT algorithm, there are several doubts:
      First, why in the scale space down sampling?
      Second, why select the key point with scale invariance?
I hope you can give a more detailed explanation! Thank you! . .

Answer (score 0):

1. It ensures that the point is not scale-variant. If you find the same point both of the image (downsampled and original) , then you say that is scale-invariant.
2. Since scaling is important when we try to objects. Who would not like to detect car in different scales ?

Answer (score 0):

The SIFT is use Laplacian operator for key-point detection that is a differential operator given by the divergence of the gradient of a color intensities of corresponding gray scale image. The gradient points in the direction of higher color intensities. The divergence of a vector field(in our case is the directions in regions with high color intensities) is an indicator of the extent to which a given point in space (more precisely, a sufficiently small neighborhood of a point) is a source or sink of this field. This means that we will get high values for example in the point of high intensities surrounded by point of low intensities.

Bluring image is performed by convolving image with Gaussian kernel. And now we can relate computing the Laplacian operator of the gray scale image with scaling and convolving image with the laplacian of the Gaussian kernel by heat equations.

Read more [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-c7233dc60f37).